# can # screw my password in sphinx

Tags: sphinx

i have a problem with sphinx, as i try to call the indexer: 
my password is: password!@#$, yet when i try to use the indexer i get:

ERROR: index 'wiki_incremental': sql_connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on '
localhost' (10061) (DSN=mysql://\'Wikidev\'replace with your db username:***@loc
alhost:3306/bchelptest).

i think all the other config is working, and i wanted to know if the # in the password is
actually getting read, and if it isnt what i can do to get it read

thanks for the help

Comment: fixed, just add \ before #, its end up like this: \#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed, just add `\` before `#` and the result is:  `\#`